# Avoid mutating a prop directly for @click

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to import and use the JetButton component from laravel jetstream. I've added the @click emit event to the jetbutton but getting the error:

*Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value.*

**Component**

```
<template>
    <jet-button @click="update()">
        Update
    </jet-button>
</template>
<script>
   method:{
       update(){ //doing something }
   }
 </script>
```

**JetButton**

```
<template>
    <button @click="$emit('click', $event);" :type="type" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-900 focus:shadow-outline-gray transition ease-in-out duration-150">
        <slot></slot>
    </button>
</template>
```

Comment: Where is the `click` event which you are emitting from the JetButton?

Comment: tbh I just want to use the jetstream button design and handle all the click methods on the main component @YashMaheshwari

Comment: If i remove it, the method doesnt trigger when clicking @YashMaheshwari

Comment: @stalwart1014 The error indicates that you're modifying a property declared in `props` (perhaps modified in `update()`). Show the component's `props` and `update()`.

Answer (score 1):

When emitting an event you need to define the method first which will be called and then emit that event from the method.

The error tells that, don't emit event directly in the prop.

On `@click` call a method defined in the JetButton component and then use `this.$emit('call')`.

**Component**

```
<template>
    <jet-button @call="update">
        Update
    </jet-button>
</template>
<script>
   methods () {
       update(){ //doing something }
   }
 </script>
```

**JetButton**

```
<template>
    <button @click="call" :type="type" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-900 focus:shadow-outline-gray transition ease-in-out duration-150">
        <slot></slot>
    </button>
</template>

<script>
methods () {
call () {
this.$emit('call')
}
}
</script>
```

Handle the event call in the component as `<jet-button @call="update">` and then define that method in the `methods()` section.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How exactly do I trigger the method update() from the component ? @click="update()" ? because the method is in the component not in the jetbutton

Comment: I did @click="this.$emit('call', event)" and @call="update" but getting  Cannot read property '$emit' of null

Comment: You understood it wrong, I added the code snippet.